# R Shiny DataTable selected row color on specific table

Tags: r, shiny, datatables-1.10

I am trying to apply different color on row selection in Data tables as mentioned in this post: [R Shiny DataTable selected row color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967894/r-shiny-datatable-selected-row-color[1]).
As it seems in the in the example below, this applies to all data tables within the app.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {background-color: black !important;}')),
  title = 'Select Table Rows',    
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('Table1')),
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('Table2'))
  )  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Table1 = DT::renderDataTable(cars, server = FALSE)
  mtcars2 = head(mtcars[, 1:8],10)
  output$Table2 = DT::renderDataTable(mtcars2, server = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there a way to explicity specify which table will be affected by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to add `#TableID` at the beggining of your style statement. Below I am applying the new highlight style only to `Table1` -

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML('#Table1 table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {background-color: black !important;}')),
  title = 'Select Table Rows',    
  fluidRow(
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('Table1')),
    column(6, DT::dataTableOutput('Table2'))
  )  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Table1 = DT::renderDataTable(cars, server = FALSE)
  mtcars2 = head(mtcars[, 1:8],10)
  output$Table2 = DT::renderDataTable(mtcars2, server = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this  Shree.

Comment: Happy to help. You can mark this as correct answer using the tick mark at the top left of this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Is there anyway to do this in bootstrap 4 in shiny, using bslib?  This doesnt seem to work in that case @Shree