# Style tag showing when using navbarpage in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I want to change the colour of rows in a DT when they are selected in my app, from the default blue. I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44969298/8506921) and it works, but for some reason it shows the text of the style tag in the app.

[image: Example of style tag showing]

I've tried changing to `fluidPage()` instead of `navbarPage()` and that gets rid of the issue - but I want to use navbarPage for my navigation tabs!

I assume I'm doing something stupid - any ideas?

EXAMPLE CODE:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

example_data <- data.table(words = c("on", "scone", "wrong", "stone"), 
                           description = c("The word on", "Scone is not on", "Not on either", "Not here at all"))

ui = shinyUI(navbarPage(tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {background-color: cornsilk !important;}')),
                        title = "Random example",

    fluidRow(
      dataTableOutput("word_searched")
    )
  )
)


server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$word_searched <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(example_data)
  })

  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This article may be helpful: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the article and have used it before but the below answer related to my specific issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the `style$tag` part within `fluidRow` and it will work. You don't need the `HTML` function either in style tag:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

example_data <- data.table(words = c("on", "scone", "wrong", "stone"), 
                           description = c("The word on", "Scone is not on", "Not on either", "Not here at all"))

ui = shinyUI(navbarPage(
  title = "Random example",
      fluidRow(
        tags$style('table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {background-color: cornsilk !important;}'),
        dataTableOutput("word_searched")
      )
)
)


server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$word_searched <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(example_data)
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help :)