# Override renderDT datatable style

Tags: css, r, shiny

In a similar way to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967894/r-shiny-datatable-selected-row-color), it is possible to change the colour of selected rows in a datatable output using `tags$style(HTML(...))` prior to the `DTOutput()` function. E.g.,

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
  tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.selected td, table.dataTable td.selected {background-color: pink !important;}')),
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('mytable'))
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(    
    datatable(mtcars,
        #style = "bootstrap" # Uncomment to see how the custom css above is overriden
    )
  ) 
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

The code above renders a plainly formatted white table that looks out of place in the dark Cyborg bootstrap theme. It does, however, have the custom css applied, which means the selected rows become pink. By contrast, if you uncomment the **style** argument within `datatable` the style of the datatable conforms exactly to the bootstrap theme, without the custom pink selected row style.

How do I apply the bootstrap theme to the datatable and override the style of selected rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `shinythemes` overrides both *css* styles and classes in *html* code. Thus, you need to take into account the new class names when applying custom *css*. The following instruction does the trick (instead of the original `tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.selected td,...))`):

```
tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.active td {background-color: pink !important;}'))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I put it here and everything worked.
```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
                tags$style(HTML('table.dataTable tr.active td {background-color: #eb7734 !important;}')),
  ...
```