# R DataTable disable highlighting row on cklick

Tags: css, r, shiny, datatable

I have a datatable in a shiny web app.
However, the default setting for datatable is that a line is highlighted in blue if it is clicked.
I would like to disable this option. It should no longer be highlighted in color.

This problem has already been discussed here a few years ago:
[R Shiny DataTable selected row color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967894/r-shiny-datatable-selected-row-color)

Apparently, however, the css / javascript command has changed. Now, it seems to be `box-shadow`:
https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/208770

However, I do not get this new option implemented in my example.
Can anyone help me?

[image]

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           selectInput("man",
                       "Manufacturer:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$manufacturer))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("trans",
                       "Transmission:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$trans))))
    ),
    column(4,
           selectInput("cyl",
                       "Cylinders:",
                       c("All",
                         unique(as.character(mpg$cyl))))
    )
  ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({
    data <- mpg
    if (input$man != "All") {
      data <- data[data$manufacturer == input$man,]
    }
    if (input$cyl != "All") {
      data <- data[data$cyl == input$cyl,]
    }
    if (input$trans != "All") {
      data <- data[data$trans == input$trans,]
    }
    data
  }))
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable row clicking using `selection = "none"` in `DT::renderDataTable`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Basic DataTable"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mpg
  }, selection = "none")
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! That was easier as I thought :)